# I'm trying to figure out the number formatter in macOS, I would like to only allow numbers and a decimal point, but I'm having trouble

Tags: swift, macos

this works great for just integer values, i found this from another stackoverflow question, but how do i set the style to allow for a decimal place as well. I'm very new to macOS, any help is appreciated!

```
class OnlyIntegerValueFormatter: NumberFormatter {
    
    override func isPartialStringValid(_ partialString: String, newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {
        
        // Ability to reset your field (otherwise you can't delete the content)
        // You can check if the field is empty later
        if partialString.isEmpty {
            return true
        }
        
        // Optional: limit input length
        
         if partialString.count > 8 {
         return false
         }
         
        // Actual check
        return Int(partialString) != nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow decimal numbers, you could update your return statement to the following

```
// ...
    return number(from: partialString) != nil
}
```

Then you are allowing integer as well as decimal numbers

There are even further options available (e.g. `maximumIntegerDigits`) to restrict your input by using `NumberFormatter` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)

Comment: thank you this is awesome!